# What influences the return value of SqlDataReader.Read()?

Tags: c#

SqlDataReader.Read() is a method which returns a bool but advanced to the next record in a recordset.

What factors influence whether true or false is returned?

Thanks

Comment: In addition to the answers posted, it will return false if there are *no* rows.

Comment: And FileNotFoundException of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the help of [SqlDataReader.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx):

> returns **true** if there are more rows; otherwise **false**.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx):

> true if there are more rows; otherwise false.